# How to select options available when we right click on any link using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

For eg, I have the below piece of code which searches for a keyword (youtube) and then would like to right click on "YouTube: Home" and then lets say I want to open this link on a NEW WINDOW or would like to copy link address. My below program gets executed until it clicks right click.

```
package java_selenium;

import javax.swing.Action;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Sample4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        WebElement Element=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name='q']"));
        Element.sendKeys("youtube");
        Element.submit();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
       
        
        WebElement el1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[normalize-space()='YouTube: Home']"));
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);
        act.contextClick(el1).build();
        act.contextClick(el1).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); 
 
        act.build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.close();
        }

}
```

I tried right clicking on a link and select options available in that context menu. But pgm is not working as expected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Sorry, but this site is not a discussion forum or programming tutorial site.  A lot more information is required other than _"pgm is not working as expected"_.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. 
Also read 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)